# Are variables case-sensitive in exprtk?

Tags: c++, exprtk

When I define an expression in my exprtk string, like

```
var x := sqrt(y);
```

and I try to add another variable

```
var X := 2*z;
```

do I get a conflict? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not give it a try?

Comment: Why use the C++ tag?  The syntax you presented is not valid for C++.

Comment: Thomas: because exprtk is a C++ library.
Robert: I just tested it here, and I get a conflict. Should I remove the question?

Comment: @LucioCarlosPimentelPaiva just answer your question yourself if you have found the answer,

Comment: Right. Thanks for the advice

Comment: I don't know if it's expected or not. But it gave me a headache for hours when I tried to debug my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of March 2017, the author of `exprtk` has added support for case sensitive variables: https://github.com/ArashPartow/exprtk/blob/master/readme.txt#L4477

Just include `#define exprtk_disable_caseinsensitivity` and you are good to go!

Comment: Nice! It didn't exist when I posted the question, it's good to know that it is supported now. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I just found the answer: variables defined within exprtk expressions are NOT case sensitive. In the example above you will get a conflict.